# What is the best way to use one object in two separate classes?

Tags: swift

That is is a bit of theoretical question. Let's say I have 3 classes:

- **ParentViewController**,
- **FirstViewController** and
- **SecondViewController**.

In the `ParentViewController` I have an object

```
let myObject = MyObject()
```

I fetch the data for this object from the web.

```
  networkHelper.fetchData { [weak self] image, text in 
    self?.myObject.image = image
    self?.myObject.text = text
  }
```

Then I want to use `myObject` both in `FirstViewController` and in `SecondViewController`.

I see few possible options:

- 1. Passing `myObject` via `prepareToSegue`
- 2. Creating a `singleton` and accessing `myObject` from any class
- 3. Fetching `myObject` from child class by calling `parent.myObject`
- 4. Doing the *networking in both child classes individually* to have 2 separate objects for 2 classes.

What would be the best one?

Answer (score 1):

There are various approach for forward communication of data from a **RootViewController** to its **ChildViewControllers**.

But since you have mentioned 4 possible options, we have to find the best from the four options.

1. **Singleton**

It is mainly used as a global instance. Its use is treated as a bad practice. Because we should hide dependencies of our application in code, instead of exposing them through the interfaces.

They inherently cause code to be tightly coupled. This makes faking them out under test rather difficult in many cases.

They carry state around for the lifetime of the application.

2. **Doing networking in both child classes**

It is a very expensive task.If we can solve our problem with only one network call, there is no need to do it twice.

3. **prepareToSegue**

It's one of the best option to pass data to the ChildViewController from RootViewController.It doesn't require any extra computation.

You only have to declare your myObject variable in your **FirstViewController** & **SecondViewController**. Within **performToSegue** you have to inject the dependency.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var myObject: MyObject!
}
```

in performToSegue in **RootViewController**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if segue.destination is FirstViewController
    {
        let vc = segue.destination as? FirstViewController
        vc?.myObject = myObject
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you create FirstViewController and SecondViewController? If you are initializing them in ParentViewController, you should initialize with the object you want to pass. Of course you in first and second view controllers you should have a property for the object and initializer methods where you can pass that object.

If you are using segues than you should go with prepareForSegue. Otherwise:

```
class FirstViewController {

    let let myObject: MyObject

    init(myObject: MyObject) {
        self.myObject = myObject
    }
}
```

and ParentViewController:

```
class ParentViewController() {
    func presentFirstViewController() {
        let myObject = MyObject()

        let firstViewController = FirstViewController(myObject: myObject)
        present(firstViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

p.s. I did not try to compile the code, there might be small mistakes.